# Is it possible to target the iPad with the iOS 4.0 SDK?

Tags: iphone, ios4, ipad

Using the iOS 4.0 SDK, can I build an application for the iPad?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

yes. You should get the newest SDK available though (currently 4.1 or 4.2 beta).

Comment: you mean with 4.0 no? and with 4.1 or 4.2 can i have choice to select one of two(iphone or iPad) for make app?

Comment: Yeah there are different templates you can choose from for iphone or ipad.  The same code can run on both platforms though.